# how to swipe gesture recognize android on MainActivity.java without creating another .java file?

Tags: android, swipe

I need a small code.i searched on google but all of them are creating a new class or ".java" file. i need to put all the code "MainActivity.java" .

Comment: `private GestureDetector mGestures = new GestureDetector() { ... };` right inside your `MainActivity`. Or a nested class.

Comment: can you give me simple example? when we swipe left msg "left" like that]

Comment: That wasn't what you asked. You might want to update your question. There are plenty of examples out there though.